# rational numbers proof: x + y, x*y

Tags: calculus

I tried to solve this , I don't know how to continue.
the question is:

$ x, y ∈ Q $

(1) Prove that $ x + y $ have to be rational number.

(2) Prove that $ x*y $ have to be rational number.

my solution:

$x = \frac{p}{q}, $ 
$ y = \frac{a}{b} $

(1) $ \frac{p}{q} +  \frac{a}{b}  = \frac{pb}{qb} + \frac{aq}{qb} = \frac{pb+aq}{qb}$

I don't now how to continue this stage.

(2) $ \frac{p}{q} * \frac{a}{b} = \frac{pa}{qb} $

same problem

thank you for your help :)

Comment: What do you know about the products $pb$, $aq$ etc, considering that $x$ and $y$ are rational numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: slow down. Calm down. Try thinking in basics.

1. What is the definition of a rational number?
2. Knowing (1), what do you need to prove about $x$ in order to show that it is a rational number?
3. Knowing (2), how can you prove that thing for the case when $x=\frac{pb+aq}{bq}$?

Comment: 1. rational number is a number that can be x/y . 2. I have no idea

Comment: @Silas2033 So are you saying that $\sqrt 2$ is a rational number? Since $\sqrt{2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{1}$? See, that's what I'm saying. **SLOW DOWN**. You are thinking too fast, and jumping to conclusions. You answered "I have no idea" after $2$ minutes. OF COURSE YOU DON'T KNOW AFTER 2 MINUTES!!! This is mathematics! It's **hard**, and it's **impossible** if you give up after $2$ minutes!

Comment: @Silas2033 Also, think about this: The answer to (1) is something like "If *blablabla*, then $x$ is a rational number". Therefore, just using this knowledge, what can you say if you prove that *blablabla* is true?

Comment: rational number is a number that can be x/y but x and y have to be integers. so $ \frac{pb+aq}{bq} $ is a rational number, because all the numbers is intergers, and integer + integer = integer . integer * integer = integer ? and the result is interger/integer - so it's rational number?

Comment: @Silas2033 Correct! You see? It wasn't *that* difficult, now was it? It's important in math to think slowly enough so that the irrational jumping to conclusion part of your mind does not overtake the rational part. You need to think in basics. Always repeat in your mind the questions "What do I know?" "What do I need to prove?" "Why am I proving this statement?"

Comment: thank you @5xum , you helped me a lot :)